# Show all products in list while creating new order manually woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woo-commerce when I create an order manually, I have to add items where i can add products. In adding products there is a search bar where i have to type three words then the products appears if it's available in product list. 
What i want is that when you add products, I need a drop down list of all my products instead of a search bar. I have this code presently:

```
   `<?php
         $row = '<td><select class="wc-product-search" name="item_id" data-allow_clear="true" data- 
         display_stock="true" data-placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 
         'woocommerce' ) . '"></select></td>
         <td><input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" name="item_qty" 
         placeholder="1" size="4" class="quantity" /></td>';
     ?>
     <tbody data-row="<?php echo esc_attr( $row ); ?>">
     <tr>
     <?php echo $row; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
     </tr>
     </tbody>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple answer for that which i figure out by myself. It's a manual process like you have to write the ID's of every product you had in your product list.

```
<?php
$row = '<td><select name="item_id">
<option selected>Select a product</option>
<option value="35" >4-Seater Cart</option>
<option value="420" >6-Seater Cart</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" name="item_qty" placeholder="1" size="4" class="quantity" /></td>';
?>
<tbody data-row="<?php echo esc_attr( $row ); ?>">
<tr>
    <?php echo $row; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```